# Perl hangs up on while loop

Tags: perl, while-loop

This code hangs up for some reason or just doesn't go any further when `while (<>) { $file .= $_};` is queried. Why is that?

As soon as I start the code with the entered text does not happen more than that it outputs `task1` and then it hangs.

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use JSON;

my $json = JSON->new->allow_nonref;
my $file = "";

print('task1');

while (<>) { $file .= $_ };

print('task2');

my $json_output = $json->decode( $file );
my ($c, $i, $cstr, $istr);
foreach my $cert (@$json_output)  {

        print('task3');
        $i = $json_output->{i};
        $c = $json_output->{c};

        $istr = join("", map { sprintf("%02x",$_) } @$i);
        $cstr = pack("C*", @$c);
        open(F, ">$istr.der"); print F $cstr; close(F);
        print('done.');

}
```

Output:

```
task1
```

Comment: What does the command line look like? If there are no other command-line arguments, `<>` will try to read from standard input.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This line

```
while (<>) { $file .= $_ };
```

is trying to read from a file specified on the command line, or if there isn't one, from standard input.  If there isn't anything piped to standard input, then it sits waiting for you to type something at the keyboard.

So I'm guessing you didn't specify a file on the command line, and your program is sitting there waiting to get input from standard input.

Also, the easier way to read in the entire file to a single variable is like so:

```
my $file = do { local $/; <> };
```

See [this article](https://www.perl.com/article/21/2013/4/21/Read-an-entire-file-into-a-string/) for other options.

Comment: is it normal that the data is output as hash?

Comment: @SussyCodingBoy Are you saying that the contents of `$file` are a hash? I suspect that you left off the `do` when copying my code.

Answer (score 3):

How do you invoke your code? The `<>` operator means that it takes input from either all the files that you specify as arguments, or from standard input. If you call your script with no arguments, it will sit and wait for console input.

If you call it without arguments, try entering a few lines of text when it is "hanging", and then type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> if you are on Linux, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> on Windows. That should make the script work.